# Writing Radon Nikodym derivative of joint distributions in terms of marginals and conditionals

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, radon-nikodym

Given two random variables $X, Y$ and two joint probability distributions  $P_{X, Y}$ and $Q_{X, Y}$ on the same product space $(\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B})$ that are given by ($A\in\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B}$)
$$ P_{X, Y}(A\times B) = \int_{A\times B} P_{X, Y}(dx, dy)=\int_{A}P_X(dx)P_{Y|X}(B, x).$$

Likewise for Q:
$$ Q_{X, Y}(A\times B) = \int_{A\times B} Q_{X, Y}(dx, dy)=\int_{A}Q_X(dx)Q_{Y|X}(B, x).$$

Then if $P_{X, Y}$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $Q_{X, Y}$ their Radon Nikodym derivative exists:
$$P_{X, Y}(A\times B) = \int_{A\times B} \frac{dP_{X, Y}}{dQ_{X, Y}}(x,y)Q_{X, Y}(dx, dy). $$

I would now like to somehow express the derivative $\frac{dP_{X, Y}}{dQ_{X, Y}} $ now in terms of $P_X, P_{Y|X}, Q_X, Q_{Y|X}$.

Is that possible and if so why and under which conditions?

So I could obviously write it as $\frac{d(\int_{A}P_X(dx)P_{Y|X}(B, x))}{d(\int_{A}Q_X(dx)Q_{Y|X}(B, x))}$ but can that be further simplified? For instance when the conditionals are absolutely continuous w.r.t. to each other or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to use your notation though I am not quite familiar with it:
\begin{align*}
P_{X, Y}(A\times B)
&=
\int_{A}P_X(dx) \int_{B} P_{Y|X}(dy, x)
\\
&=
\int_{A}\frac{dP_{X}}{dQ_{X}}(x) \, Q_X(dx) \int_{B} \frac{dP_{Y|X}}{dQ_{Y|X}}(y, x)\, Q_{Y|X}(dy, x)
\\
&=
\int_{A \times B}\frac{dP_{X}}{dQ_{X}}(x) \frac{dP_{Y|X}}{dQ_{Y|X}}(y, x) \, Q_{X,Y}(dx, dy),
\end{align*}
so
$$
\frac{dQ_{X,Y}}{dP_{X,Y}}(x,y) = \frac{dP_{X}}{dQ_{X}}(x) \frac{dP_{Y|X}}{dQ_{Y|X}}(y, x).
$$

Note that the derivation only holds if the corresponding Radon-Nikodym derivatives exist!

Is this what you were looking for? Hope it helps..

**UPDATE: What happened in each step:**

*First step:* wrote out the probability as an integral and using conditional distributions (almost identical to your first equation)

*Second step:* Used Radon-Nikodym derivatives (under the assumption that they exist!) of $P_{X}$ w.r.t $Q_{X}$ and of $P_{Y|X}$ w.r.t $Q_{Y|X}$ in order to rewrite the integrals with respect to the measures $Q_{X}$ and $Q_{Y|X}$, respectively.

*Third step:* "Pulled out" the integral over $B$ and replaced $Q_X(dx)Q_{Y|X}(dy, x)$ by $Q_{X,Y}(dx, dy)$ (the same conditioning argument that you used).

*Final implication:* Comparing my derivation with your last equation yields the result.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Can you tell me what happens in each step? I.e., what kind of formula are you using in the first equality, what are you doing in the second equality and then in the third one?

Comment: I updated my answer by adding explanations.

Comment: So can you tell me what assumptions must hold for all the radon nikodym derivatives to exist? Also is it sufficient to assume that $P_{X,Y}<< Q_{X, Y}$? I.e., does this also imply that $P_X<< Q_X$ and the same for the conditionals? If so why?

Comment: There is no general rule for the Radon-Nikodym derivative to exist. One typical case is that both $P_{X,Y}$ and $Q_{X,Y}$ have probability densities $p_{X,Y}$ and $q_{X,Y}$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure (or w.r.t. some other measure) and $p_{X,Y} = 0$ whenever $q_{X,Y} = 0$. In such a case all the Radon-Nykodym derivatives you need do exist.
Further, $P_{X,Y} \ll Q_{X,Y}$ always implies $P_{X} \ll Q_{X}$, but I am not entirely sure about the conditionals in the very general case, so I will be careful not to state anything wrong here.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! Could you give a brief reasoning why absolute continuity of the joint measures imply absolute continuity of the marginals?

Comment: Sure. $Q_{X}(A) = 0 \Leftrightarrow Q_{X,Y}(A \times \mathcal Y) = 0 \Rightarrow P_{X,Y}(A \times \mathcal Y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow P_{X}(A) = 0$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi yes thanksa!

Comment: sorry again, I was looking at the proof again and was wondering if that also works for general subset of the product sigma algebra or only for rectanuglar sets?

Comment: and another question: why does the Radon Nikodym derivative of the conditionals depend on both x and y and not just y?