# Transforming Radon Nikodym derivatives

Tags: lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

I am currently confused by the (abuse of?) notation regarding the Radon Nikodym derivative in many proofs.

What I am currently struggling with in particular is a proof of the classical information processing inequality of f-divergences:

Let $P_{X,Y}(E) = \int_{\mathcal{X}}P_{Y|X}(E^x|x)P_X(dx)$ be a measure on $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$ with $E$ being a measureable subset of $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$ and $E^x = \{y:(x,y)\in E\}$. Likewise, let $Q_{X,Y}(E) = \int_{\mathcal{X}}P_{Y|X}(E^x|x)Q_X(dx)$, i.e., both $P_{X,Y}$ and $Q_{X,Y}$ are using the same kernel!

Now I have two questions:

1.) There is this equation:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{Q_{X,Y}}\biggl[f\biggl(\frac
{dP_{X,Y}}{dQ_{X,Y}}\biggr)\biggr] &= \mathbb{E}_{Q_{X,Y}}\biggl[f\biggl(\frac
{d(\int P_{Y|X}dP_X)}{d(\int P_{Y|X}dQ_X)}\biggr)\biggr]
\end{align}
Here, $f:(0, \infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is some convex function.
So this notation seems to imply that you could somehow transform the numerator and denominator of the radon nikodym derivative independently. However, to write it as a fraction is just a notation - in reality it is not a fraction but just a function where you cannot simply plug in something for the numerator and something for the denominator. So what is going on here? How can I proof that statement?

2.) The second question is the claim that
$$\int_{\mathcal{Y}}\frac
{d(\int P_{Y|X}dP_X)}{d(\int Q_{Y|X}dQ_X)} dQ_{Y|X}(dy,x) = \frac{dP_X}{dQ_X}$$

For discrete random variables it would be clear what is going on, i.e., the $Q_{Y|X}$ cancels and then summation over $P_{Y|X}$ is 1 such that only the fraction of the marginals remain. However, with the integrals and in particular the integrals within the Radon Nikodym derivative, I do not understand what is going on.

3.) My third question is, why does the following equation hold?
$$\frac{dP_{X,Y}}{d(P_{X,Y}+Q_{X,Y})}=\frac{dP_{X}}{d(P_{X}+Q_{X})}.$$
Again, since they also use the notation $P_{X,Y}(E) = \int_{\mathcal{X}}P_{Y|X}(E^x|x)P_X(dx):=P_{Y|X}P_X$ (and likewise for $Q_{X, Y}$) they seem to suggest that you can somehow pull out the kernel $P_{Y|X}$ both in the numerator and the denomiator and then cancel them. But first of all there are actually integrals involved and secondly, again as in 1.) this is not really a fraction but just a notation. So what exactly is going on here and how can I proof this?

Comment: is $\int P_{Y \mid X}\,dP_X$ a notation for $P_{X, Y}$?

Comment: The joint is equal to that integral formula. I have written this also in the first formula of that question. Or are you asking because i have omitted the $x$ and $y$ sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

1.) This appears to just be notation. Just interpret $\int P_{Y \mid X}\,dP_X$ as $P_{X,Y}$.

2.) For this I'll write
$$P((X, Y) \in E) = \int 1_E(x, y)P(X \in dx, Y \in dy) = \int 1_E(x, y)P(Y \in dy \mid X = x)P(X \in dx).$$
From this we have
$$P(X \in dx, Y \in dy) = P(Y \in dy \mid X = x)P(X \in dx).$$
Such an equality of differentials should be interpreted as saying that the measures on both sides integrate to the same thing against every measurable set. We want to show that
$$\int_{Y}\frac{dP}{dQ}(x, y)Q(Y \in dy \mid X = x)Q(X \in dx) = P(X \in dx).$$
But this is clear because for any set $A$,
$$\int_{A}\int_{Y}\frac{dP}{dQ}(x, y)Q(Y \in dy \mid X = x)Q(X \in dx) = \int_{A}\int_{Y}\frac{dP}{dQ}(x, y)Q(X \in dx, Y \in dy) = P(X \in A).$$

3.) Here we take the same approach. We want to show that
\begin{align}
\frac{dP_{X}}{d(P_X + Q_X)}(x)(P(X \in dx, Y \in dy) + Q(X \in dx, Y \in dy)) &= P(X \in dx, Y \in dy). 
\end{align}
This follows from the assumption that the conditional distributions  of $Y \mid X$ are the same for both $P$ and $Q$:
$$P(X \in dx, Y \in dy) + Q(X \in dx, Y \in dy) = P(Y \in dy \mid X = x)(P(X \in dx) + Q(X \in dx)).$$

Actually, you can use things like $\frac{dP_X}{dQ_X}(x) = \frac{P(X \in dx)}{P(Q \in dx)}$ as long as you interpret this as $\frac{dP_X}{dQ_X}(x)Q(X \in dx) = P(X \in dx)$. Then the cancellations you observed like in the discrete case are made rigorous, and the same proofs work. For example, $\frac{P(X \in dx, Y \in dy)}{Q(X \in dx, Y \in dy)} = \frac{P(X \in dx)}{Q(X \in dx)}$.

Comment: Hi so first of all thank you for your answer and your efforts!
I have a little trouble though with the way you are proving the things. So you are substituting infinitesimals as if they were functions. But that is mathematically actually not the correct thing to do, since the infinitesimals are an expression that are bond to the integral, and one always has to substitute the entire integral with corresponding infinitesimals and not just the infinitesimals.

Comment: And also you are treating the Radon Nikodym derivatives as if you could just simply work with the numerator and denominator independently, and then for instance multiply by the denominator of that Radon Nikodym derivative etc. But again that is just a suggestive notation in reality the Radon Nikodym derivative is just a function not a fraction.
But it is exactly that what I have problems with and what my question was for: To find out how these equations can be proven mathematically rigorously without using this notation where it seems that one could just treat infinitesimals as functions.

Comment: @guest1 I showed you how to prove these rigorously. You just verify the definition of Radon Nikodym derivative. Infinitesimals are measures, and all equalities of infinitesimals are rigorous since they are equalities of measures. For example, the equality $P(X \in dx, Y \in dy) = P(Y \in dy \mid X = x)P(X \in dx)$ should be interpreted as equality of the measures on both sides of the equation: $\int 1_A(x, y)P(X \in dx, Y \in dy) = \int 1_A(x, y)P(Y \in dy \mid X = x)P(X \in dx)$. Note $P(X \in dx)$ is the same as $dP_X(x)$.

Comment: When equality of fractions of measures are involved it should be interpreted as equality after multiplying through by a factor. For example, we often write $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} = f$ to mean $d\nu = f\,d\mu$. In this problem, we can compute $$\frac{P(X \in dx, Y \in dy)}{Q(X \in dx, Y \in dy)} = \frac{P(Y \in dy \mid X = x)P(X \in dx)}{Q(Y \in dy \mid X = x)Q(X \in dx)} = \frac{P(X \in dx)}{Q(X \in dx)}.$$ Although this looks like an unrigorous equality of fractions, it is really just the rigorous equality $$\frac{dP}{dQ}(x, y) = \frac{dP_X}{dQ_X}(x),$$ which shows that $\frac{dP_X}{dQ_X}$ exists

Comment: So for instance with Riemann integrals, physicists often multiply and divide by infinitesimals like dx etc. But this is not allowed. The only thing you can do is apply theorems like integration by substitution. The results are often the same thats why it is justified to do what physicists do but it is not mathematically rigorous.

Comment: And the same goes on here as well: an infinitesimal measure is always connected to an integral it does not exist outside of an integral. The notation of the radon nikodym derivative is just notation but it is not a fraction of infinitesimals it is just a function f.

Comment: And I dont agree with your statement that $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=f$ is supposed to mean $d\nu = f d\mu$. In fact the latter is usually shorthand to write that the measure $\nu$ has a density w.r.t. to $\mu$ i.e., it is shorthand for $\nu(A)=\int_A f d\mu$. 
And $d\nu = f d\mu$ wouldnt even be defined since infinitesimals dont exist outside of integrals, it is only used as a notation to denote the previous integral.

Comment: Yes, $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} = f$ and $d\nu = f \,d\mu$ and $\nu(A) = \int_{A}f\,d\mu$ for all measurable sets $A$ all mean the same thing. Actually my previous example that $\frac{dP}{dQ}(x, y) = \frac{dP_X}{dQ_X}(x)$ is not correct, so it is always good to verify conclusions reached via fractional calculations. Upon reflection, my recommendation is to use the fractional calculation to guide the formal verification. Points 2 and 3 have easy verifications since you know what identities of measures to use. I can write them out  fully at some point

Comment: Hi it would be really great and helpful if you could write them out at some point! Why do you think is you previous example wrong? The following answer suggests it is correct: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643649/writing-radon-nikodym-derivative-of-joint-distributions-in-terms-of-marginals-an/4644663?noredirect=1#comment10252382_4644663

Comment: It is true that $\frac{dP_X}{dQ_X}$ exists, but it does not have the form $\frac{dP_X}{dQ_X}(x)  = \frac{dP}{dQ}(x, y)$ that I got from manipulating fractions. Working it out directly, I get a different formula for $\frac{dP_X}{dQ_X}(x)$